# How to make an Azure DevOps Query which returns only on side of link?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

We are working on implementing an architecture review which affects a specific subset of work items.  I created the following query: 
[image: picture of query]

The result includes the downstream work items, which is what I want.  However, it also includes the work items marked as with the `Architect Decision`, which I don't want.  My ultimate goal is to see on a dashboard how many work items are blocked by architect decisions which are pending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AzDO does not support that. If you want to see a plain list, you should use a flat query. As workaround, you may write your own job through REST API (as example):

1. Find epics, features, stories, and bugs without the `Blocked by Architect Decision` tag and with open work items contain the `Architect Decision`. Add to these work items the `Blocked by Architect Decision` tag.
2. Find epics, features, stories, and bugs with the `Blocked by Architect Decision` tag and without open work items contain the `Architect Decision`. Remove from these work items the `Blocked by Architect Decision` tag.

Then you can search your blocked work items with a flat query and the `Blocked by Architect Decision` tag.

The Rest Api methods:

1. [Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).
2. [Update a work item tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#add-a-tag).

Additionally, you`ll receive a notification when your work items are unblocked.